# PWA implementation in Angular 9

Tags: angular

I implementing PWA in Angular 9 in that when we are generating production build at that time ngsw-worker.js file automatically generated in the dist folder so need to create again separate sw.js file.

2. I have not app.js file in project so where we can add that functionality in main.ts or app.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

as far as I understand your question, you are asking where should you register your service worker? (correct me if I am wrong)

– The ideal way of registering the service worker is in `app.module.ts` file. If you are using `angular/cli`, this thing will be taken care of. (For more info you can refer their docs [here](https://angular.io/api/service-worker/SwRegistrationOptions).)

– You can also register the service worker in `main.ts` file or wherever (any ts file) you want. (this method is not appreciated)

```
  . . .

  if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
    // you can specify environment in IF CONDITION as per requirement
    navigator.serviceWorker.register('/ngsw-worker.js');
  }
```

Comment: ok thanks.. 
shall i add PWA indexedDB methods(get,delete) in main.ts or app.component.ts.?
can you plz give some example/demos.